# Stokes's theorem problem.

Tags: integration, stokes-theorem

> Evaluate the surface integral $\int \int (curl F) \cdot n dA $ directly for the given F and S.

$$F = [z^2, -x^2, 0] $$ and S is the rectangle with verticies (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,4,4), (1,4,4)

So the formula in Stokes's theorem to find the line integral involves finding the curl of F and n which is the normal unit vector... but how do we find n here?

What is S for here? Does it help us find n?

Comment: You need to be told an orientation on the rectangle, or else you only know the flux up to a factor of $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the orientation of the rectangle is not given, here I will assume clockwise  orientation (as seen from top). We can first find the plane on which the rectangle lies.

We can get directional vectors of two lines from the vertices $A(0,0,0), B (1,0,0), C (1,4,4), D (0,4,4)$

$\vec{AD} = (0-0,4-0,4-0) = (0,4,4), \vec{DC} = (1-0,4-4,4-4) = (1,0,0)$

So normal vector of the plane $\vec{N} = \vec{AD} \times \vec{DC} =  \begin{vmatrix} i & j & k \\ 0 & 4 & 4 \\ 1 & 0 & 0   \end {vmatrix} = \, (0,4,-4)$

And equation of the plane is $ \, z = y$.

Unit vector $n = \frac{\vec{N}}{||N||} = \frac{(0,4,-4)}{4\sqrt2} = \frac{(0,1,-1)}{\sqrt2}$, $dS = \sqrt2 dA$ (as $|n \cdot k| = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$).

So, $\int \int (curl F) \cdot n dS = \int \int (curl F) \cdot (0,1,-1) dA$ ...(i)

$ curl F = \nabla \times F = \begin{vmatrix} i & j & k \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\ z^2 & -x^2 & 0\end {vmatrix} = \, (0,2z,-2x)$

Now using $z = y$ from the equation of the plane and we can integrate using (i)

$\int \int (curl F) \cdot n dS = \int_0^4 \int_0^1 (0,2y,-2x) \cdot (0,1,-1) \, dx \, dy$

$ = 2 \int_0^4 \int_0^1 (x + y) \, dx \, dy = 20$

Comment: Why are the limits of y 0 to 4....because that's the range of the y component in the square right? Why is het equation of the plane z = y? What significance is that?

Comment: As the normal vector of the plane is (0,4,-4), the equation of the plane is $0.x+4y-4z = d$. Now as the plane passes through (0,0,0), we can substitute values and see $d = 0$. So the equation of the plane becomes $4y-4z = 0 \implies y-z = 0$. So if you visualize the plane, it is at $45^0$ angle to the $XZ$ and $XY$ planes.

Comment: @Jwan622 and yes the range of $y$ in rectangle is $0$ to $4$ and $x$ is $0$ to $1$, hence the limits for our integral.

Comment: @Jwan622 It's not true that $dS = \| \boldsymbol N \| dx dy$. What is correct is
$$d\boldsymbol S =
\frac {\boldsymbol n} {\boldsymbol n \cdot \boldsymbol k} dx dy,$$
where $\boldsymbol n$ is an arbitrary normal. Also, $\Delta \times \boldsymbol F$ should be $\nabla \times \boldsymbol F$, and, since the boundary points are not given in sequential order, it's not clear why you call the chosen orientation positive.

Comment: @Maxim I know $d\boldsymbol S = \frac {\boldsymbol n} {|\boldsymbol n \cdot \boldsymbol k|} dx dy$. I showed that way because my calculation showed it was canceling out. I will check a little later... may be I made a mistake in calculation. I will fix the symbol.. it was a typo. As far as orientation, I mentioned in the beginning what I assumed as it was not clear from the question (as there was no particular sequence - clockwise or counter-clockwise).

Comment: @Maxim Thanks for pointing out. I did find a mistake in my calculation. While I wrote $dS = ||N|| dA$, I had not made the $k$ component of the vector $1$. I somehow thought I had.

Comment: @Jwan622 there was a mistake in my calculation. The answer is $20$ and not $80$. Apologies. Also if the orientation of the rectangle is opposite of what I have assumed the answer will be $-20$.

Comment: Exactly, you can just divide your previous answer by $|\boldsymbol N \cdot \boldsymbol k|$, there is no need to find the unit normal. You're correct that it's more accurate to write $\boldsymbol n/|\boldsymbol n \cdot \boldsymbol k|$ and specify that $\boldsymbol n$ is arbitrary but has the same direction as $ d\boldsymbol S$. Re the orientation, I'm saying there is nothing that justifies calling the orientation given by $\vec {DC} \times \vec {AD}$ negative and the orientation given by $\vec {AD} \times \vec {DC}$ positive, it's an arbitrary choice.

Comment: @Maxim yes I know but I just modified the way I usually do. Regarding orientation, yes that is correct. I just randomly chose clockwise orientation / a downward normal vector. It was wrongly written as positive - fixed it.

Comment: What is k? I'm confused a bit how you got the normal vector

Comment: @Jwan622 I took $3$ points in the plane to find two vectors in the plane. Then the cross product of those two vectors gave me the normal vector to the plane. Then I divided by the magnitude to get unit normal vector (n). $k$ (as in $i, j, k)$ is the $k$ component of the vector. You are taking scalar product of $n.k$ to find the component of the unit normal vector in $k$ direction.

Comment: Oh I see, k is nothing more than just the k variable in i,j,k

Comment: Last thing, how did you get your normal vector? When you divide by magnitude, it's still over $\sqrt{2}$. How did this cancel?

Comment: @Jwan622 $n = \frac{(0,1,-1)}{\sqrt2}$. So $|n.k| = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ so $n / |n.k| = (0,1,-1)$. Basically if you make the $k$ component $1$ as a practice in your normal vector, the magnitude will always cancel out.

Comment: Sorry why does $|n * k| = 1/\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Ugh that's teh only thing I"m confused about... like why isn't the normal vector 0,4,-4?

Comment: $k$ would mean $i, j$ components are zero so it is really (0,0,1). $|n.k| = | \frac{(0,1,-1)}{\sqrt2}.(0,0,1)|$. So dot product will give you 1/ $\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\vec{n}$ is the *unit* normal vector to the surface.

The (not necessarily unit) normal vector of the plane $ax+by+cz+d=0$ is $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$. Find the plane passing through your points and then find unit normal vector and normalize it. Alternatively you can use the cross product of the vectors connecting the points together (followed by normalization).